# How can I get the age of a tweet using Tweepy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to use Tweepy to get a list to get a list of tweets that are older than a week from a specific user but I can not figure out how to get the age of a tweet. As of right now I know how to get the list of tweets but I cant find anything in the docs about getting the age of the tweet. Does such a thing even exist with Tweepy or should I just use a different library? If so, what library can I use that would have this capability? Thank you!

Comment: Can you please post the code you're using to collect the tweets?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually really easy.  Each tweet you collect is tagged with a BUNCH of data, including the date of posting.  You can access them like this with the `Status.created_at` property:

```
import tweepy, time, datetime

CONSUMER_KEY = '#'
CONSUMER_SECRET = '#'
ACCESS_TOKEN = '#'
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = '#'
key = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
key.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(key)

results = api.search(q='tryptophan')

dates = []

for tweet in results:
    dates.append(tweet.created_at)

ages = []

for d in dates:
    # to compare against time.time(), we must use seconds since the epoch (1/1/1970)
    # time.time() returns the current time, in seconds, since 1/1/1970
    age = time.time() - (d - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
    ages.append(age) # age in seconds

for i in range(0,len(ages)):
    print 'Tweeted:', str(dates[i]) + ', age in seconds:', ages[i]
```

Results:

```
Tweeted: 2014-05-03 05:39:40, age in seconds: 4564.01300001
Tweeted: 2014-05-03 04:45:47, age in seconds: 7797.01300001
Tweeted: 2014-05-03 04:21:40, age in seconds: 9244.01300001
Tweeted: 2014-05-03 03:56:01, age in seconds: 10783.013
Tweeted: 2014-05-03 01:24:53, age in seconds: 19851.013
Tweeted: 2014-05-03 00:44:49, age in seconds: 22255.013
Tweeted: 2014-05-03 00:31:50, age in seconds: 23034.013
Tweeted: 2014-05-02 22:23:15, age in seconds: 30749.013
Tweeted: 2014-05-02 22:00:12, age in seconds: 32132.013
Tweeted: 2014-05-02 21:22:18, age in seconds: 34406.013
Tweeted: 2014-05-02 20:54:45, age in seconds: 36059.013
Tweeted: 2014-05-02 20:33:59, age in seconds: 37305.013
Tweeted: 2014-05-02 20:31:45, age in seconds: 37439.013
Tweeted: 2014-05-02 15:16:43, age in seconds: 56341.013
Tweeted: 2014-05-02 15:05:03, age in seconds: 57041.013
```

The seconds since the epoch thing is a little funky, you can read more [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html).  The age here is in seconds, but you can easily convert to minutes by dividing by 60, hours by dividing by 60 again, and days by dividing by 360.

Comment: The author asked how to retrieve tweets later than a week old tho. Even though he can get created_at data, the api still wont give you tweets older than a week.